# Как добавить текст в toolbar android?

Tags: java, android, toolbar

Необходимо в стандартный toolbar (Не отдельная View) добавить какой-либо текст помимо заголовка. Иконки как добавлять я знаю, а вот с текстом проблема

Comment: Попробуй `getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle("subtitle")`

Comment: Попробую, а таким образом можно бесконечное кол-во добавлять текстов, или только 1?

Comment: Если посмотреть в исходники support-тулбара, то там в разметке внутри LinearLayout находятся две TextView: `@+id/action_bar_title` и `@+id/action_bar_subtitle`. Поэтому можно добавлять только 1 заголовок и 1 подзаголовок, если используешь стандартный тулбар.